# Get timezone list from moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to create a select with the following values,

```
Eastern Standard Time (EST, GMT-5:00)
Central Standard Time (CST, GMT-6:00)
Mountain Standard Time (MST,GMT-7:00)
Phoenix Standard Time (PNT, GMT-7:00)
Pacific Standard Time (PST, GMT-8:00)
```

is there a way to do it through moment.js ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/getting-zone-names/

Comment: `"Phoenix Standard Time"` and `PNT` are not valid.  Also, you should be sure to understand "Time Zone != Offset", as described in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Let me ask this - is there a *reason* you need moment to produce this list for you?  If you have a fixed list of 5 time zones and you know what the strings are, what more would you expect moment to produce?  Why not just write the list in plain HTML?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`moment.js` has timezone support via [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/), so if you load the full set of timezones, you can filter for the time zones you care about by iterating through `moment.tz.names()`, and then calling [`format("z, Z")`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/) to get the string you want.

```
> moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("z, Z")
"PDT, -07:00"
> moment.tz("2016-01-01", "America/Los_Angeles").format("z, Z")
"PST, -08:00"
```

Comment: This is fine, but understand that the abbreviation and offset will change based on the moment in time.  May or may not be what the user expects in a time zone picker.

Comment: Yep, that's why I included the second example, as the first one assumes the current time. OP, make sure you know whether you want the dropdown to show the *current* timezone offsets, or show offsets for some specific datetime.

Comment: Thank you, where can I find documentation about format method ?

Comment: Petran, my answer includes a link to that. :-) Just click.